# IIS(10) error in Event Viewer (The resource identifier failed to decrypt)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

I have recently moved a .net web app (v3.5) hosted to a IIS 10 server after which the app recycled itself couple of times and everything went down. I manually recycled the IIS once and the app started working, but now i have these warnings continuously popping up in the eventviewer logs and i have no clue how to solve this. The app seems to be running ok, but these warnings are somewhat alarming since it has filled up the entire eventviewer app logs. Can someone shed some light on whats going on? i found a related thread on this but didn't really get to a solution, would be great if someone could chime in. The error is as follows,

```
3012 
   An error occurred processing a web or script resource request. The resource identifier failed to decrypt. 
   5/25/2020 1:27:56 PM 
   5/25/2020 7:57:56 AM 
   709f3592d2ad4343bf5965471b800362 
   1621 
   516 
   0 
   /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-132348489440653768 
   Full 
   / 
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ 
   ERP-APP 

   20172 
   w3wp.exe 
   IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
   HttpException 
   Unable to validate data. at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s, Purpose purpose) at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  
   http://192.0.1.26/AppWeb/WebResource.axd?d=CO7ammFOcmKBQVIxHLAoEA2&t=633735960628463707 
   /AppWeb/WebResource.axd 
   192.0.1.1 

   False 

   IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
   1016 
   IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
   False 
   at System.Web.Configuration.MachineKeySection.EncryptOrDecryptData(Boolean fEncrypt, Byte[] buf, Byte[] modifier, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean useValidationSymAlgo, Boolean useLegacyMode, IVType ivType, Boolean signData) at System.Web.UI.Page.DecryptString(String s, Purpose purpose) at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context
```

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1233087.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The cause behind the warning is The machineKey on the IIS host is not sufficient to decrypt some of the information which is present on the server.

to resolve the issue you could try below things:

1)manually put the decryption key in your web.config:

```
<machineKey decryptionKey="..." />
```

2)use iis manager GUI machine key feature and configure Identical Machine Keys on both IIS servers.

- open iis manager, select your site.
- double click on the machine key feature from the middle pane.
- Remove the check-box from both “Automatically Generate at runtime” options and then click Generate Keys.

[image]

- Click on apply from the action pane.
- Go to IIS on your second server and paste the keys generated on the first server to the machine keys respectively.
- restart both the iis server after doing changes.